# Asynchronous method queue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, queue

I am attempting to implement an asynchronous method queue in Javascript as seen in [this blog post](http://www.dustindiaz.com/async-method-queues/)

Here's what I have so far:

```
function Queue() {
  this._methods = [];
  this._response = null;
  this._flushed = false;
}

(function(Q){

  Q.add = function (fn) {
    if (this._flushed) fn(this._response);
    else this._methods.push(fn);
  }

  Q.flush = function (response) {
    if (this._flushed) return;
    this._response = response;
    while (this._methods[0]) {
      this._methods.shift()(response);
    }
    this._flushed = true;
  }

})(Queue.prototype);
```

I can't seem to get it to work as advertised, although the code looks correct to me. When I call the flush function I get `this._methods is undefined` on the line `while (this._methods[0]) {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you using it? If you're doing:

```
var q = new Queue();
q.flush("foo");
```

...you shouldn't be getting that error, and I'm not: http://jsbin.com/iduji3

Comment: Yeah, I'm using it as a constructor. That's what's so weird.

Comment: Okay, looks like there was a scoping problem with the way I was using Queue#flush as a callback. It is working okay.

Comment: @Adam: Ah, if you were using it as a *callback*, your problem would be that `this` won't be what you're expecting in the callback. Two blog posts on this: [You must remember this](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html) and [Mythical Methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) The second one is probably more on-target for what you're trying to do.

Comment: J. Yeah, I was inadvertently passing the function into a different scope. Dumb mistake. Moral: probably shouldn't have been coding at 3am. Calling queue.flush from within an anonymous function works fine.